# Load content when scroll down like facebook does in wall posts

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I'm creating the effect that when I scroll my document to the bottom watching a set of post and get the last one, I start loading new posts in the same way as facebook does in the wall.

Well, the effect is not the same.

In facebook, when new content is loaded, the position in the document only scroll up a little bit to see that new content is ready but in the mine the effect differ. Sometimes it scroll down and other to the middle, etc...

Does anyone know any technic I could use?

Thanks.

Comment: there are a bunch of jquery examples at http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/#.UCwp0qOyC70

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with  masonry [infinite scroll](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html)

and also with  [Infinite Scroll by Paul Irish](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it using simple php and jquery trick. See [HERE](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html)